# Image formats compatible on both a Mac and a PC

Tags: windows-xp, images, osx-lion, macbook-air

What image formats can be captured by the Grab application or the equivalent keyboard shortcuts (Command-Shift-3 and Command-Shift-4) on a Mac and viewed on a PC?

Answer (score 3):

Basically all of them. The default format is PNG, which can be opened in Paint (and probably other default apps) in Windows XP and later. You can change the format to GIF, JPEG, PDF, TIFF, and a few others, all of which are trivially opened on and relatively recent version of Windows (with the possible exception of TIFF, but not by much).

Comment: The TIFF file format is compatible in Windows as well. Though you may need third-party software for it. However, I've used TIFF files in Windows even back in Windows 98.